# Regex for merging lines if new line does not start with hyphen in Notepad++

Tags: regex, pdf, replace, notepad++, pdftotext

I am converting a book from pdf to notepad text. In pdf row length is fixed and that result half of sentences are transferred to a new row in text output.

I need a regular expression for *notepad++* that does the following:

If new line did not start with `-` merge it to previous line and do  (empty space).

Any other options that works for making text proper will be accepted.

Comment: That will remove all proper new lines like "-Hey, this is a character speech"

Comment: You probably look for a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): [`\R(?!-)`](https://regex101.com/r/yL5nX1/1) Please always include the regex you tried/failed and proper input samples for being able to reproduce your problem and find issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Description

```regex
\r?\n(?!-)
```

**Replace with:** `_` a space, not the underbar that's shown here.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- find new line characters that are not followed by a `-`
- remove the new line characters which then merges the lines together

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/jE2mI1/1

**Sample text**

```
-line 1
line 2
line 3
-line a
line b
line c
```

**After Replacment**

```
-line 1 line 2 line 3
-line a line b line c
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you post some sample text from your log?

Comment: This regex did not work. I press Ctrl + H add \r?\n(?!-) i Find what, add empty space in replace with, and result is that all lines become a single line.